# HTML Hide Table rows

Tags: css, html

So I am trying to add an incrementing number to the first cell of a HTML table. Which I have done using examples found in this forum. What I want to do next is hide any row that only contains the number in the first cell. The only real option I have available is css but I am unsure if it is possible. The code I have so far is

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table td > *:empty {
  display: none;
}
tr > td:empty {
  background-color: yellow;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" empty-cells:hide;>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So no Javascript? I don't think this is possible in just CSS I'm afraid. I don't think you can target the parent of an object depending on the objects state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check below snippet meets your requirement.

http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/D2ZDA

Here I'm hiding all sibling TR elements if the first TR is empty.
Using CSS, you can not control parent as there are no parent selectors.

Here is the code -

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
tr > td:first-child:empty,
tr > td:first-child:empty ~ td {
  display: none;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" empty-cells:hide;>
  <tr>
    <td>Has Text</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Has Text</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post relevant code in your answer? Bootsnipp requires an account to view the code, so is not ideal for an answer.

Comment: Thank you to you both for the help. This works great

Answer (score 0):

Building on @CharanKumar answer, what you could do is remove the first column, and apply the numbering to the row with text. You could then add some `padding` and a `border-right` to simulate a separate cell.

It would look like below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
tr > td:first-child:empty,
tr > td:first-child:empty ~ td {
  display: none;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px 5px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" empty-cells:hide;>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```